# Cannot connect correctly with Nodemon, attempting to connect with mongoDB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, nodemon

Attempting to run backend section of a project, and when I go to my localHost 5000 it says Server Is Ready, but when I try the path http://localhost:5000/api/users/ or http://localhost:5000/api/users/seed it says Cannot GET /api/users/. In my terminal, here's the code it throws.

```
[nodemon] starting `node --experimental-modules backend/server.js`
Serve at http://localhost:5000
(node:3612) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 
127.0.0.1:27017
at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri 
(C:\Users\lumpy\Desktop\aaaaa\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:845:32)
at C:\Users\lumpy\Desktop\aaaaa\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:345:10
at C:\Users\lumpy\Desktop\aaaaa\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\lumpy\Desktop\aaaaa\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\lumpy\Desktop\aaaaa\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1135:10)    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\lumpy\Desktop\aaaaa\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:344:20)
at file:///C:/Users/lumpy/Desktop/aaaaa/backend/server.js:7:10
at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:152:23)
at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:166:24)
at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3612) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated 
either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which 
was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the 
CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see 
https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)     
(node:3612) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, 
promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Both users and products are in the same folder, and while it can access and display the products fine, it cannot display the users. Before I noticed this, I was attempting to connect it to Mongo Compass, but it read "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017"

I never know what code to put up that's relevant, but here's the rest of my code.

userModel

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
name: { type: String, required: true },
email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
password: { type: String, required: true },
isAdmin: { type: Boolean, default: false, required: true }
},
{
timestamps: true,
}
);
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
export default User;
```

userRouter

```
import express from 'express';
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import data from '../data.js';
import User from '../models/userModel.js';

const userRouter = express.Router();

userRouter.get(
'/seed',
expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
const createdUsers = await User.insertMany(data.users);
res.send({ createdUsers });
})
);

export default userRouter;
```

server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import data from './data.js';
import userRouter from './routers/userRouter.js';

const app = express();
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/aaaaa', {
useNewUrlParser: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true,
useCreateIndex: true,
});

app.get('/api/products/:id', (req, res) => {
const product = data.products.find((x) => x._id === req.params.id);
 if (product) {
res.send(product);
} else {
res.status(404).send({ message: 'Product Not Found, gat dammit' });
}

});
app.get('/api/products', (req, res) => {
res.send(data.products);  
 });

app.use('/api/users', userRouter);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.send('Server is ready');
});

 app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
res.status(500).send({ message: err.message }); 
 });

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`Serve at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose connection is an async function, for which you need to use async await. try using:

```
(async() => {
await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/aaaaa', {
useNewUrlParser: true,
useUnifiedTopology: true,
useCreateIndex: true,
});
})();
```

in your server.js file

Answer (score 0):

In server.js after importing userRouter try adding
dotenv.config();